# ngx-bootstrap Bootstrap4: after closing modal is still there

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a problem using ngx-bootstrap with Bootstrap 4: after successfully opening a modal, if I close it I can see the backdrop covering all my page, so my app gets unusable.

If I use the config parameter { backdrop: false } when I open the modal... when I close it no backdrop is visible, but body element gets modal-open class, so again my app is totally unusable.

There's the code:

Component: product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';

import { config } from '../config'
import { ProductService } from '../product/product.service';
import { Product } from '../product/product';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product-list',
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css'],
    providers: [ProductService, BsModalService]
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

    loadedProducts: Array<Product> = [];

    public modalRef: BsModalRef;

    constructor(
        private productService: ProductService,
        private modalService: BsModalService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.productService.loadProductList().then(
            serverProducts => this.loadedProducts = serverProducts);

    }

    deleteButtonClicked(product2BeDeleted: Product,
        confirmDeleteModalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>): void {

        if (config.showConfirmDeleteModal) {
            this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(confirmDeleteModalTemplate);
        }

    }

}
```

Component template: product-list.component.html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">

        <h4 class="card-title">Listado de productos</h4>

        <div *ngIf="loadedProducts.length == 0" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <span class="fa fa-warning"></span> No hay productos disponibles
        </div>

        <table *ngIf="loadedProducts.length > 0" class="table table-striped">

            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr *ngFor="let productRow of loadedProducts">

                    <td>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/product/', productRow.id]" title="Editar este producto"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                            <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                        </a>

                        <button title="Eliminar este producto"
                            (click)="deleteButtonClicked(productRow, confirmDeleteModalTemplate)"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>

                    <td>{{productRow.sku}}</td>
                    <td>{{productRow.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{productRow.price}}</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

        <ng-template #confirmDeleteModalTemplate>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmDeleteModalLabel">Confirmar eliminación de un producto</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Cerrar" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Estas a punto de eliminar este producto:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                <p><strong>¡Ten en cuenta que esta acción no se puede deshacer!</strong></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="modalRef.hide()">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>

    </div>
</div>
```

I hope anyone can help me, I haven't found any solution, I try to get as close as possible as the demos on ngx-bootstrap doc, but... no way.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue yesterday. The solution for me was to remove the BSModalService from the providers list in the component. When you add the service to the providers list the component will get its own instance of the service instead of the singleton instance created in the Modal module. This is what causes the strange behavior of the backdrop not going away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have some issues with this solution: If I remove BsModalService from providers of my component... Then I supposse I have to remove too the modalService on my component's constructor, and then... I can't call this.modalService.show() to show the modal... am I right?

Comment: No, by importing the Modal module the service is already "provided". Children components (your component) have access to any service that is provided by a parent.

Comment: Sorry Ironflash, but I still don't understand your answer. Please see the official documenttion of ngxbootstrap: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals. They are asking you to import BsModalService on a COMPONENT, and please see the constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) THE SERVICE IS INJECTED IN CONSTRUCTOR, so when we want to open the modal we execute this.modalService.show(template); How can I access "show" method of the service if I don't inject the service in the constructor??

Comment: I think you are mixing the concept of a provider and dependency injection. As long as the service is provided, any sub component can inject it. In this case the Modal module provides the service. Therefore, your component must only inject it. If you look at their examples they do not have "providers: [BsModalService]" but they do inject the service into the constructor. All I'm saying is remove the BsModalService from your providers list and keep it in the constructor.

Comment: Finally I understood it, I simply removed BsModalService from providers array of my component as you recommended and... et voila! solved! Thank you very much for your answer and your patience, Ironflash!!